# Make AMP URL as Canonical

Tags: amp-html

Hi i have a doubt on AMP versions with respect to SEO. I will explain by taking a example

Site: `www.example.com`  (Non AMP)

```
ww.example.com/my-blogs              #(Non-AMP Version)
www.example.com/my-blogs/first-blog  #(Non-AMP Version)
www.example.com/my-blogs/second-blog #(Non-AMP Version)
```

When AMP came to trend, i converted few **modules** to **AMP** version like **my-blogs**

After Conversion

```
www.example.com/my-blogs             #(AMP Version)
#and all blog under this too as AMP
www.example.com/my-blogs/first-blog  #(AMP Version)
www.example.com/my-blogs/second-blog #(AMP Version)
```

Changed the **URL** of **Non-AMP version**

```
www.example.com/my-blogs.html             #(Non-AMP Version)
www.example.com/my-blogs/first-blog.html  #(Non-AMP Version)
www.example.com/my-blogs/second-blog.html #(Non-AMP Version)
```

The reason for keeping AMP Version to default is it was **faster**. 
So for all AMP version canonical was **(.html)**

Got to know google indexes only canonical version, which mean .html needs to be indexed again. But my sitemap includes all AMP Version urls.

Now being my site partial in AMP and rest in NON-AMP. can i **take out .html version for my-blog module and keep only AMP version setting canonical to itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have your blog pages as AMP and set those pages as the canonical version. See [Make your page discoverable (What if I only have one page?)](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery#what-if-i-only-have-one-page?)